# Writing a visual studio plugin?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I'm looking for resources on writing a visual studio 2008/2010 plugin, preferably a book of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Really good web page:
   http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx
2. Book "Professional Visual Studio®
   2008 Extensibility", Keyvan Nayyeri.
3. Forum:
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/threads

Comment: this mztools link is the best Visual Studio extensibility resource on the internet. Carlos Quintero rocks!

Comment: I'm using these sources(mztools) - they are great!

Comment: I'll give you correct answer on this, three awesome resources!

Answer (score 1):

http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/01/02/LearnVSXNowPart1.aspx

http://www.professionalvisualstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has a podcast episode: ["Inside a Visual Studio Plugin - CodeRush with Mark Miller"](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=196)